# GRUB2 /etc/grub.d/ 40_custom multi-boot

Tags: grub2, scripts

I am adding GoBoLinux to Windows Vista and Ubuntu 12.04 with GRUB2 on the MBR but I am not clear on the script or how to devise a script to replace 40_Custom. Loading the GoBo GRUB to it's own root seems the only practical place so I need a script

```
menuentry "GoBoLinux" {
set root=(hd0,4)
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7 ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
}
```

Seems to be used for Linux or

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1CFC7A8DFC7A60C6
    chainloader +1
 }
```

But I have seen variations on these but I have been unable to understand exacly how they are used and if GrubCustomiser is used instead of editing the file directly how do you decide on which type of boot is selected. What I have read so far does not quite make it clear in either case. Explanations or further reading would be handy.

Comment: First type of entry works for Debian based installs as they put a link to the most current kernel in / (root). The Windows type entry works as Windows (and Lilo) put boot info in a partition boot sector. I would just let os-prober find your new install. Then maybe copy that into 40_custom and turn off os-prober so as not to have duplicate entries. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen And: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries I am not a fan of grub customizer as it adds its own scripts which later can cause issues, but it is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for that, getting there slowly. The Customiser makes a right mess of the script files which is why I am trying to understand direct editing in the hopes that I might learn something but I had not taken on board the need to mount drives before Probing, obvious really.